# Hiding of alternative text not happening

Tags: sifr

I am using sifr in the content management system cmsms, and for the first time ever I've experienced a problem with sifr.

http://www.improvingbiz.co.uk/index.php?page=e-commerce

Sifr is showing the text as well as the flash, resulting in this double headline!

I have sifr replacing `#title` and using the following in screen CSS:

```
.sIFR-hasFlash #title {
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size:0px;
}
```

...to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Required me to put the sIFR stylesheet into the CMS style sheet, it didn't like a link to an external sheet.

Answer (score 0):

In general, sIFR is not a technique that should be used today.

Instead, use the @font-face css property, and allow users using older browsers to see their default fonts. This way you have progressive upgrades for the users who can support the newer features, but you don't break things for users of older (or very old) browsers.

Headlines should be images if you feel strongly about how they render. Style them with css if you need to. Look here for examples: http://www.csszengarden.com/

Flash is a really bad thing to require for titles because it slows load times incredibly for users of slower computers (netbooks, for example).

Comment: You should work to get your corporate guidelines changed. He's specifically asking about using it for headlines, which is a particularly bad place to use it. Images work far more universally and are less likely to bug out in the manner he's describing.

Comment: I agree, I originally was using images, and prefer to, but in this case i want a well rendered title, but as part of a content management system. The customer wants to be able to change these titles, but without needing to know photoshop. It seemed that sifr was the obvious choice.

Comment: Have you considered rendering the titles server-side? I'm just so jaded about sIFR compatibility issues...

Comment: I thought sifr was the solution and not a problem, if you have flash, it displays a very small file, if not you get text. I'm open minded and will always take on board anyone's views, but surely there has to be some balance between accessibility and design here.

I take the view that if you've got a very old browser then you're not really worth my time, really, who are these people on ie6? If you don't want flash on your netbook, don't install the player, are you saying that great works of art such as http://www.heineken.com.br/ shouldn't take advantage of technology to please the minority?

Comment: @font-face really isn't ready for primetime yet... rendering issues and browser support don't really cut it. And server-generated images don't have the advantages of being able to use computed widths for the DOM, etc... +1 for avoiding flash and pushing for CSS3, but overall not sure this answers the original question.